# Anonymous Method Not Working

Tags: c#

```
ComboBoxEdit encoderCombo =
{
   if (slot==1) return cmbEncoder1; 
   else if (slot==2) return cmbEncoder2; 
   else if (slot==3) return cmbEncoder3; 
   else return cmbEncoder4;
};
```

Comment: What language is this? .NET is not a language and if this is supposed to be C# then, well, many things are wrong :-)

Comment: It's c#, or at least I'm forcing it to be :)

Comment: Well, that's far from C#. Start by describing what you are trying to do, provide some context, what error message are you getting, things like this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just inline the whole thing and get rid of the anonymous method?

```
ComboBoxEdit encoderCombo = slot == 1 ? cmbEncoder1 :
                            slot == 2 ? cmbEncoder2 :
                            slot == 3 ? cmbEncoder3 :
                            cmbEncoder4;
```

If you really must use an anonymous method, you could do something similar to this:

```
Func<ComboBoxEdit> encoderCombo = () => 
                            slot == 1 ? cmbEncoder1 :
                            slot == 2 ? cmbEncoder2 :
                            slot == 3 ? cmbEncoder3 :
                            cmbEncoder4;
```

Which will capture the value of `slot` in the closure (which may cause unpredictable behavior as things get more complex).

Comment: I am practicing anonymous methods because they don't want to get into my keyboard so I want to use them as much as possible :)

Comment: @Daniel - "they don't want to get into my keyboard"??? That does SO not make any sense!

Comment: +1 for the inline. No need for an anonymous method here.

Answer (score 2):

If this is C#, then that's not a valid anonymous function.

```
Func<ComboBoxEdit> encoderCombo = delegate {
    if (slot==1) return cmbEncoder1; 
    else if (slot==2) return cmbEncoder2; 
    else if (slot==3) return cmbEncoder3; 
    else return cmbEncoder4;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It'll be valid if you replace

```
ComboBoxEdit encoderCombo=
```

with

```
Func<ComboBoxEdit> encoderCombo = () =>
```

Note - C# 3.0 and above.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you *could* do it like this:

```
ComboBoxEdit encoderCombo = new Func<ComboBoxEdit>(() =>
{
     if (slot==1) return cmbEncoder1; 
     else if (slot==2) return cmbEncoder2; 
     else if (slot==3) return cmbEncoder3; 
     else return cmbEncoder4;
}).Invoke();
```

That's kind of hideous, though ;)